# What do "$\pm_s$" and "$\mp_t$" mean in a formula (in particular, one for the roots of a quartic polynomial)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I am going through [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) solution of a quartic equation and have got stuck with notation in the solution. The solution is given by this equation:

> $$x=-\frac{B}{4 A}+\frac{\pm_{s} W \mp_{t} \sqrt{-\left(3 \alpha+2 y \pm_{s} \frac{2 \beta}{W}\right)}}{2}$$

What is confusing me is the significance of the following two symbols $\pm_s$ and $\mp_t$.

Can anyone explain what they mean please? I apologise for the relative simplicity of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says:

> Note: The subscript $s$ of $\pm_s$ and $\mp_s$ is to note that they are dependent.

It also says:

> Remember: The two $\pm_s$ come from the same place in equation (7'), and
>   should both have the same sign, while the sign of $\pm_t$ is independent.

Thus, in other words, these symbols give you a convenient way of writing down all four solutions in a single formula. Those four solutions are characterised by the choice of signs in the formula; there is $\pm_s$ and $\pm_t$, which are independent, and hence together give you 4 choices: $(\pm_s, \pm_t) =(+,+), (+,-), (-,+)$ and $(-,-)$.

Comment: sorry, I still do not understand.

Comment: I've added further explanation; is it clearer?

Comment: Yup, thanks, very clear now!

Comment: One last thing: as the +/- on the t is inverted, does this mean it has to have the opposite signe of the "s"?

Comment: As a standalone formula, whether $\pm_t$ is inverted or not is immaterial (because it appears only once in the formula). The reason, it seems, that the formula you cite reads $\mp_t$ is because the article derives that formula from a previous equation, so the authors supposedly wished to preserve the correspondence between the roots.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!